# ¿Como indicar cuando pulsemos en una tab de tabLayout no muestre el color de selección?

Tags: android

Hola estoy haciendo una aplicación Android donde tengo una tabLayout con 3 tab las cuales 2 contiene fragments y una me lanza una activity. La cuestión es que cuando pulso en la tab que lanza la activity no quiero que se muestre el color de indicador de debajo de la tab, pero en las otras dos si.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta con lo siguiente:

```
tuTabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorHeight(0);
```

O bien en sus propiedades solo agrega un color transparente `app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/transparent"`

***Ejemplo***

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/mis_tabs"
        ...
        ...
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/transparent"
        ... />
```

***ó***

Agregando cualquiera de las siguientes propiedades:

```
app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"



 android:tabStripEnabled="false" android:alpha="0"
```